# Why does this coffeescript blow up with the following error

Tags: coffeescript

```
Person = (name, age, job) ->
  @name = name
  @age = age
  @job = job
  @sayName = ->
    console.log(@name)

kim = new Person("Kimothy Lozado", 37, "Skip Tracer")


console.log kim.sayName()
```

### Returned Error

```
TypeError: Object function () {
      return console.log(this.name);
    } has no method 'sayName'
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aero/Downloads/m.coffee:11:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aero/Downloads/m.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not quite defining classes properly. Namely you need a constructor and need to use `:`s instead of `=`s unlike regular js.

Do this instead:

```
class Person
  constructor: (@name, @age, @job) ->

  sayName: ->
    console.log(@name)

kim = new Person("Kimothy Lozado", 37, "Skip Tracer")


console.log kim.sayName()
```

Demo in a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4e8xZ/

Here's a great [article](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html) on CoffeeScript class from the little book of CoffeeScript for your reference.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was translating this straight from javascript as a way to learn coffeescript.

Comment: no problem! a great place to try it out is the in browser interpreter on the main coffeescript website.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend agconti answer for creating classes, but here I want to answer to why this error occurs.

#### When you write a constructor in javascript:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var someone = new Person('someone');
```

The variable `someone` is assigned to the returned object of the `new keyword`.

But if the constructor returns a function:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  return function(){};
}

var someone = new Person('someone');
```

Unfortunately, instead of getting the new created object, `someone` is assigned to the function returned by the constructor.

#### If we look at the compiled code of your coffee:

```
Person = function(name, age, job) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.job = job;
  return this.sayName = function() {
    return console.log(this.name);
  };
};
```

We see that the constructor returns a function. this happens because **coffescript always returns the last expression of a function**.

#### You can fix it by returning nothing:

```
Person = (name, age, job) ->
  @name = name
  @age = age
  @job = job
  @sayName = ->
    console.log(@name)
  return
```